# Add MongoDB to Circle CI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, circleci

I want to add MongoDB database creation to my Circle CI configuration.
Actually I was thinking about this .circleci/config.yml like this

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.10
      - image: mongo:4.2.0
        port: 27017:27017
        environment:
          - MONGODB_USERNAME: "myrootuser"
          - MONGODB_PASSWORD: "mypassword"
    working_directory: ~/IV
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Database Setup
          command: "mongodb && mongo --eval 'db.createUser({ user: 'myrootuser', pwd: 'mypassword', roles: [ { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' } ] })"
      - run:
          name: Install package json dependencies
          command: npm install .
      - run:
          name: Run test
          command: npm test
```

The fact is that it's failing and doesn't recognize the command to create the database.

Anyone can help me to build this configuration file?

Thank you

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I see few mistakes in your *config.yml*:

- You should point to the proper circleci/mongodb docker image:

```
 - image: circleci/mongo:4.2.0
```

- You need to run `- setup_remote_docker` after the checkout step:

```
steps:
 - checkout
 - setup_remote_docker
```

- Before trying to run any mongo command you need to install mongodb with the following code:

```
 - run:
      name: MongoDB Install
      command: |
         sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

- The quotes in your mongodb command are wrongly used; the command itself doesn't need to be quoted. Also you're using simple quotes only, breaking in this way the string. Change the command line for the following one:

```
command: mongodb && mongo --eval 'db.createUser({ user: "myrootuser", pwd: "mypassword", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] })'
```